# Classifying edges in DFS on a directed graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

Based on a DFS traversal, I want to classify edges (u, v) in a directed graph as:

- Tree edge: when v is visited for the first time as we traverse the edge
- Back edge: when v is an ancestor of u in the traversal tree
- Forward edge: when v is a descendant of u in the traversal tree
- Cross edge: when v is neither an ancestor or descendant of u in the traversal tree

I was following a [GeeksForGeeks tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tree-back-edge-and-cross-edges-in-dfs-of-graph/) to write this code:

```
class Graph:
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.time = 0
        self.traversal_array = []
        self.v = v
        self.graph_list = [[] for _ in range(v)]
 
    def dfs(self):
        self.visited = [False]*self.v
        self.start_time = [0]*self.v
        self.end_time = [0]*self.v
        self.ff = 0
        self.fc = 0
 
        for node in range(self.v):
            if not self.visited[node]:
                self.traverse_dfs(node)

    def traverse_dfs(self, node):
        # mark the node visited
        self.visited[node] = True
        # add the node to traversal
        self.traversal_array.append(node)
        # get the starting time
        self.start_time[node] = self.time
        # increment the time by 1
        self.time += 1
        # traverse through the neighbours
        for neighbour in self.graph_list[node]:
            # if a node is not visited
            if not self.visited[neighbour]:
                # marks the edge as tree edge
                print('Tree Edge:', str(node)+'-->'+str(neighbour))
                # dfs from that node
                self.traverse_dfs(neighbour)
            else:
                # when the parent node is traversed after the neighbour node
                if self.start_time[node] > self.start_time[neighbour] and self.end_time[node] < self.end_time[neighbour]:
                    print('Back Edge:', str(node)+'-->'+str(neighbour))
                # when the neighbour node is a descendant but not a part of tree
                elif self.start_time[node] < self.start_time[neighbour] and self.end_time[node] > self.end_time[neighbour]:
                    print('Forward Edge:', str(node)+'-->'+str(neighbour))
                # when parent and neighbour node do not have any ancestor and a descendant relationship between them
                elif self.start_time[node] > self.start_time[neighbour] and self.end_time[node] > self.end_time[neighbour]:
                    print('Cross Edge:', str(node)+'-->'+str(neighbour))
            self.end_time[node] = self.time
            self.time += 1
```

But it does not output the desired results for the following graph:

[image]

which is represented with:

```
self.v = 3
self.graph_list = [[1, 2], [], [1]]
```

The above code is not identifying the edge (2, 1) as a cross edge, but as a back edge.

I have no clue what to adapt in my code in order to detect cross edges correctly.

In a discussion someone gave this information, but I couldn't make work:

> The checking condition is wrong when the node has not been completely visited when the edge is classified. This is because in the initial state the start & end times are set to 0.
>
> if the graph looks like this:
>
> - 0 --> 1
> - 1 --> 2
> - 2 --> 3
> - 3 --> 1
>
> When checking the 3 --> 1 edge: the answer should be a back edge.
>
> But now the `start/end [3] = 4/0` ; `start/end [1] = 1/0`
>
> and the condition `end[3] < end[1]` is false because of the intialization problem.
>
> I see two solutions,
>
> 1. traverse the graph first and determine the correct `start/end [i]` values, but it needs more time complexity, or
> 2. use black/gray/white and discover the order to classify the edges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some issues:

- By initialising `start_time` and `end_time` to 0 for each node, you cannot make the difference with a *real* time of 0, which is assigned to the very first node's start time. You should initialise these lists with a value that indicates there was no start/end *at all*. You could use the value -1 for this purpose.
- The following statements should not be inside the loop:

  ```
      self.end_time[node] = self.time
      self.time += 1
  ```

  They should be executed *after* the loop has completed. Only at that point you can "end" the visit of the current node. So the indentation of these two statements should be less.
- There are several places where the value of `self.end_time[node]` is compared in a condition, but that time has not been set yet (apart from its default value), so this condition makes little sense.
- The last `elif` should really be an `else` because there are no other possibilities to cover. If ever the execution gets there, it means no other possibility remains, so no condition should be checked.
- The condition `self.start_time[node] > self.start_time[neighbour]` is not strong enough for identifying a back edge, and as already said, the second part of that `if` condition makes no sense, since `self.end_time[node]` has not been given a non-default value yet. And so this `if` block is entered also when it is *not* a back edge. What you really want to test here, is that the visit of `neighbor` has not been closed yet. In other words, you should check that `self.start_time[neighbor]` is still at its default value (and I propose to use -1 for that).

Not a problem, but there are also these remarks to make:

- when you keep track of `start_time` and `end_time`, there is no need to have `visited`. Whether a node is visited follows from the value of `start_time`: if it still has its default value (-1), then the node has not yet been visited.
- Don't use code comments to state the obvious. For instance the comment "increment the time by 1" really isn't explaining anything that cannot be seen directly from the code.
- Attribute `v` could use a better name. Although V is often used to denote the **set** of nodes of a graph, it is not intuitive to see `v` as the **number** of nodes in the graph. I would suggest using `num_nodes` instead. It makes the code more readable.

Here is a correction of your code:

```
class Graph:
    def __init__(self, num_nodes):
        self.time = 0
        self.traversal_array = []
        self.num_nodes = num_nodes  # Use more descriptive name
        self.graph_list = [[] for _ in range(num_nodes)]
 
    def dfs(self):
        self.start_time = [-1]*self.num_nodes
        self.end_time = [-1]*self.num_nodes
        for node in range(self.num_nodes):
            if self.start_time[node] == -1:  # No need for self.visited
                self.traverse_dfs(node)

    def traverse_dfs(self, node):
        self.traversal_array.append(node)
        self.start_time[node] = self.time
        self.time += 1
        for neighbour in self.graph_list[node]:
            # when the neighbor was not yet visited
            if self.start_time[neighbour] == -1:
                print(f"Tree Edge: {node}-->{neighbour}")
                self.traverse_dfs(neighbour)
            # otherwise when the neighbour's visit is still ongoing:
            elif self.end_time[neighbour] == -1:
                print(f"Back Edge: {node}-->{neighbour}")
            # otherwise when the neighbour's visit started before the current node's visit:
            elif self.start_time[node] < self.start_time[neighbour]:
                print(f"Forward Edge: {node}-->{neighbour}")
            else: # No condition here: there are no other options
                print(f"Cross Edge: {node}-->{neighbour}")
        # Indentation corrected:
        self.end_time[node] = self.time
        self.time += 1
```